# Symfony doesn't create logs in production environment

Tags: symfony, monolog

I'm having yet another weird case where Symfony 3.3 doesn't produce logs in production environment. My main config has following monolog section:

```
monolog:
  channels:
    - job.execution
    - job.clean-up
    - job.notification
  handlers:
    main:
      type: rotating_file
      max_files: 10
      path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%/application.log'
      level: debug
      formatter: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
      channels:
        - '!event'
        - '!job.execution'
        - '!job.clean-up'
        - '!job.notification'
    console:
      type: console
      channels: ['!event', '!doctrine']
      formatter: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
    job.execution:
      type: rotating_file
      max_files: 10
      path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%/job.execution.log'
      level: debug
      formatter: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
      channels: job.execution
    # same definitions for job.notification and job.clean-up
```

This config is not redefined in any environment-specific config, including config_prod.yml. However, my application doesn't log anything to files in `prod` environment (console emits what i've expected), while it does so in dev and test environments. The most common reason would be fingers crossed handler and/or level filter set too high, but this is not the case. What am i missing?

Comment: Have you checked permissions in `/var/logs` for the Symfony project?

Comment: @ReynierPM yes, everything is alright and dev/test logs are created even if i wipe directory contents. The problem persists across two machines, so i think there is just some switch i don't know about yet.

Comment: @Etki late but can you add your config_prod.yml?

Comment: @goto i'm afraid it is long gone, but the actual production deployment works fine. Guess it was something with environment on my workstation.