# Symfony logs issue

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, monolog

I am using Symfony `"symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",` .and Mono log to track all logs.

Log will write only when enabling true in app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod',true);
```

My problem is if I enable to true then the user can see error exception.Can anyone help me how I can achieve to write log when enabling to false in App kernel.

Ref:
[Symfony doesn't create logs in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958482/symfony-doesnt-create-logs-in-production-environment)

**Updated
Config_prod**

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "php://stderr"
            level: debug
```

Comment: Can you add the config of monolog for `config_prod.yml` and `config.yml`? What are the rights of you `app/logs` folder?

Comment: @goto update question .i have tested in both localhost as well as server its not owrking. even i write logs to db its not inserting .only isnert when i set to dev

Comment: In which folder are you looking for you logs?

Comment: app/logs folder and it will create dev.log but not prod.dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should let `new AppKernel('prod', false);`

You are looking in the wrong folder.
Your configuration is writing log in the general php error log

```
    path: "php://stderr"
```

Change your `config_prod.yml` to :

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        # [...]
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
```

Don't forget to clear the cache with `--env=prod`

Comment: but even if write to db its not writting may i know why.thanks

Comment: have added but files is not creating prod file

Comment: @goto.thanks a lot works fine.only issue is,if i make error in code user will see for example Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (

Comment: @goto.do you have any idea to show some custom error so that i can show html page

Comment: @vision Change back your appKernel to `new AppKernel('prod', false);` . For custom error pages in `prod`: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look in to this snippet,

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type: fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler: nested
    nested:
        type: stream
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
    console:
        type: console
        process_psr_3_messages: false
```